# How to prevent screenshot on Asp.net MVC web application

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, screenshot

As per client requirements, we need to prevent screenshots of our web application. We also need to prevent taking screenshots from third party tools as well (ex: snipping tool).

Please help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: You simply cannot, we only can disable right click not taking screenshot. [`You check this document additionally`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-it-possible-to-prevent-users-from-taking-screenshots-of-webpage/)

Comment: is there any possible restricting from browser level ?

Comment: For restricting screenshot, no we cannot stop it, we can only disable right click and restict to directly copy content nothing more, nothing less. Becasue, we cannot stop user pressing `prtSc` button on keyboard.

Comment: is there any possibility in OS level ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely possible to prevent screenshotting of a web application.

There is no way to make this possible from browser level.

The only way I would recall right now is to have an Android Application (I am not sure about Apple) render your Webpage. It is possible to set an App Security Policy which makes you in-able to screenshot the app on your device.

Although it is obviously still possible to take a picture of the physical device.

Finally, there is no foolproof method of preventing screenshotting of any web application. Anything your eyes can see, can be captured in one way or another.

[Microsoft Article About App Security Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-protection-policy-settings-android)